# Unable to write to a file when reading a GPS serial port

Tags: python, gps

I am able to read GPS data through gpsd and gps pipe. But when I try to read GPS data in python code and write to a file in the same code. The file remains empty

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0')
f=open("myFile.txt","w+")
while 1:
        x=ser.readline()
        print (x)
        f.write('writing to a file \n')
```

GPS data is displayed correctly and myFile.txt is created. But when I open it is blank. Can anyone help me on this?

Note: I have tried this while using reading other devices through the USB-port and it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please flush after using.   Add f.flush() after your write, or open your file with a zero buffering size.

Answer (score 2):

The data is held in a memory buffer because memory is faster than disk i/o. Your data would be written to the file once you `close` the file, but I guess you want to read it wile you're writing it? To do that, the f.flush() suggested by @Gerard will cause the memory buffer to be written to your file; or at least to the system's disk cache if it's using one. You may also wish to consider adding an [`os.fsync(f)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) following the `f.flush`. This will ensure that the system's disk cache is also written to the file, and avoid data loss in the event of an "unexpected event".

As a general practice, I think I would avoid using a zero-sized buffer for your file. That would defeat the purpose of using memory buffers, which is to keep things moving briskly forward. But feel free to try it - the performance reduction may be irrelevant, depending upon your application: `f=open("myFile.txt","w+",0)`